# How to make curved edge in a rectangle shape in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Am trying to achieve this without using image as background, wanted to be done in xlm drawable

[image: Here is image of what am trying to achieve]

Comment: Have you checked this one : https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout

Comment: What's the closest you have gotten to this with XML drawables?

Comment: is it possible without using any library

Comment: It is possible, you have to make a drawable of this shape and add it as a background to your view group.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="200dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="240dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <size android:width="400dp"
        android:height="500dp"/>

</shape>

Comment: that is the closest i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="-200dp"
    android:right="-200dp"
    android:top="-340dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">

        <solid android:color="@color/dark_orange" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Change left-right margin as per your requirements. That will change curve.[image]